# Create an history object with database data and external datas

Tags: mysql, triggers, history

I face a complicated problem by creating an history for my mysql tables.
My mysql database look like this:

[image: my database]

So basically, i want to create a tuple SiteHistory for each creation, update and delete of `Site`.

First I tryed to do it with a trigger but the field `agent_name` is provided from an external windows active directory and I can't access it from mysql.

The other option is to do an insert in `SiteHistory` in my app for each create, update or delete but for maintenance reason, that can happen to insert, update or delete tuples directely in the database.

If you have a better solution to offer, thanks to you.

Comment: What about creating the Sitehistory with a TRIGGER, but letting the agent_name empty, and then from your app you do an `UPDATE sitehistory SET agentname='blabla' WHERE id_site=the_current_id`  ?

Comment: Sorry, I ll edit but I always want to create a SiteHistory when update and delete...

Comment: I see, then a TRIGGER is clearly the way to go. You should find a way to update the record created by your trigger after your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find a proper solution so i use variables.

When i call my database, i set a variable and this variable is used in the trigger.
see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)